# php class constuctor text before property

Tags: php, php-8.2

i trie to figure out what the use of the "text" is before te propery/variable in the contructor. What is the use of "TableGatewayInterface" in the constructor in the example below?

```
use Laminas\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

private function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
{
     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}
```

Comment: @MarkusZeller i do not understand :-(

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/constructor_promotion

Comment: If you're just asking what `TableGatewayInterface` means - it's a [type-hint](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php). It means the function can't be called with any other type of variable, or a TypeError will be raised.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought you meant what value the property has before defined. But read the link I sent, anyways, because it explains your question, too with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It states that `$tableGateway` property must come from `TableGatewayInterface`, must be declared in that aliased struct. It means that You cannot simply make an instance with such constructor, with parameter of any value of Your choice, but with **named parameter** strictly from `TableGatewayInterface`.

Here is nice insight for You: [List of Types Supported By PHP](https://amitmerchant.com/php-type-declarations/#list-of-types-supported-by-php)

Research PHP named parameters and return type declarations.